# JS syncing classes? If one element has a class another should have one too

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are a lot of similar questions regarding JS and checking if an element has a specific class. I still got a problem which I can't solve.
I have a navigation hamburger, which transforms to an X when clicked on (using CSS and JS) and opens a drop down menu. The hamburger and that drop down menu is only visible at a specific media query. So if you open the menu by clicking on the hamburger, resize the window so the hamburger and the menu disappear, resize it back (hamburger appears again, but the menu wont since it automatically closes), the hamburger is still displayed as an X, because it doesn't update.
I noticed that the drop down menu (which I didn't code) has a class assigned to it, depending if it's open or not. Same for the hamburger animation. If it has the class "is-active", it's displayed as an X, if not, it's displayed as the hamburger.

Now I want to sync the hamburger with the drop down. So if the menu has the class "is-open" assigned to it, the hamburger should have "is-active" assigned to it, if not, "is-active" should be removed.

I tested this code:

```
 if (dropdownmenu.classList.contains('is-open')){
    hamburger.classList.add("is-active");
 } else {
    hamburger.classList.remove("is-active");
 }
```

The problem is, that JS doens't check if constantly. So when I resize the window, it wont do anything. How can I sync this up?
Sorry for my bad English and my beginner JS understanding.

Comment: What kind of behaviour are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your code into the [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) handler:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    if (dropdownmenu.classList.contains('is-open')){
        hamburger.classList.add("is-active");
    } else {
        hamburger.classList.remove("is-active");
    }
};
```